# PDO bindValue() adds apostrophes around value

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement, bindvalue

I want to CREATE a table using using PDO prepared statments. The problem is that bindValue adds `''` around the binded value. I don't understand why this happens. How can I avoid this so that my table name is set as `users` and not `'users'`? Thanks.

Code:

```
<?php

$table = "users";

try {

  $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test", "root", "");
  $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

  $sql = "CREATE TABLE `:table` (id INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL)";
  $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->bindValue(':table', $table);
  $stmt->execute();

} catch(PDOException $e) {

  echo $e->getMessage();

}

?>
```

Here is the result in phpmyadmin:

[image]

Comment: You can't bind table names and column names. You'll need to pass it in directly, though you should verify it first if it's coming from a form.

Comment: If I can`t use PDO prepared statments with table names and column names how can I avoid SQL injections when the table name comes from $_POST?

Comment: Create a list of table names and column names, or grab it from the database. Verify that the value coming from the form matches what already exists before using it.